# Swift: How to create a global extension to use everywhere for a Double or Int?

Tags: swift, extension-methods

Here's my problem: I am trying to create a global extension for Double (or Int) which can be used in every ViewController without repeating the code at the top of every ViewController file.

for instance:

```
extension Double {
    var mileToFeet: Double {return self * 5280}
}
```

Of course I can call it like this:

```
let feet = 26.mileToFeet
```

Obviously this works when I put the extension at the top of the ViewController and use it withing the code, but where can I place extension so that I can use it everywhere?

I tried to put it into AppDelegate, but that doesn't work?
Am I on the right track there?

Thanks

Comment: Swift top-level declarations are internal, put it anywhere and it'll be accessible everywhere in your module (project)

Comment: Not related to your question, but if you're doing lots of unit conversion you may want to use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmeasurement

Comment: Just add new file (iOS Swift) to your project, give it a name (Extensions Double.swift) and place your extension there. No need to add public keyword.

Comment: Thanks, Leo Dabus, that worked well.

Answer (score 8):

You need to make your extension `public` if you're defining it in another module:

```
public extension Double {
    var mileToFeet: Double { return self * 5280 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be placing the code at the top level. As in not inside any view controller or any other class for that matter. Like this:

```
extension Double {
    // Your code
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...
}
```

**Not** this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    extension Double {
        // Your code
    }

    // ...
}
```